# Matlab Negative parameters of Mejier G function

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-integration, bessel-functions

Is it possible that meijerG function contain a negative value (i.e. is `{-1,0,0}`)? I tried both Mathematica and Matlab to compute this meijerG function but they generate an error that this `meijerG` is not defined for the given parameters`.

Here is my code:

```
D = (0.6);
lg1 = lg2 = 1;
G = evalin(symengine, sprintf('meijerG([[0], []], [[-1,0,0], []],%f)',(D/(lg1*lg2))));
CD = -((2*D)/(lg1*lg2*(log(4))))*G;
```

Here I have also attached the image of the function from the text.

[image: function]

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of `meijerG`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/meijerg.html):

> No pair of parameters `ai - bj, i = 1, …, n. j = 1, …, m`, should differ by a positive integer [...] . Otherwise, `meijerG` returns an error.

Complex numbers are valid for any coefficent; however in you case you have `a0-b0 = 1` which is forbidden.

Comment: Thank you, Bentoy, for your explanation. It cleared a lot of confusions. So from your comment, I can presume that the original function is incorrect? above I have also attached the image of the function from the text. I would really appreciate if you can comment on that and suggest some thing? error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know anything about this special function. I cannot help you more. Maybe try to look for the relationship between meijer G and Bessel K_0 functions, you may find the correct parameters...

Answer (score 0):

I quickly looked at that. If one expand log2(1+x) into Taylor series, substitute \gamma->x^2, then integral would be

```
S K0(x) x^m dx = 2^(m-1) G((m+1)/2)^2
```

see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+K0(x)+x%5Em+dx+from+0+to+Infinity) for details. `G` is gamma-function and for argument like (k+1/2) it is expressed via binomial coeff times sqrt(\pi), see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for details.

After all that you have infinite sum of terms with polynomials over `lambdas` and `b` and some binomial coefs and \pi etc. Whether it could be summed or not - I don't know...